# What is etcd looking for in 127.0.0.1:4001?

Tags: linux, centos, etcd

I'm trying to set up a test cluster using etcd 2.3.7 installed from CentOS RPM on CentOS 7.1.  On the **Loader 1** I executed:

```
etcdctl member add loader2 http://10.11.51.231:2380
```

And received response which confirmed the operation completed successfully.

Similarly:

```
etcdctl member add loader3 http://10.11.51.231:2380
```

with all default settings, and here's what I see:

## Loader 1 10.11.51.166

```
    systemctl status etcd -ln1
    etcd.service - Etcd Server
       Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/etcd.service; disabled)
       Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-02-19 14:33:18 IST; 28min ago
     Main PID: 19009 (etcd)
       CGroup: /system.slice/etcd.service
               └─19009 /usr/bin/etcd --name=default --data-dir=/var/lib/etcd/default.etcd --listen-client-urls=http://localhost:2379

    Feb 19 15:02:03 loader3 etcd[19009]: cannot get the version of member a4803061db803edc (Get http://10.11.51.166:2380/version: dial tcp 10.11.51.166:2380: getsockopt: connection refused)
```

Tried to see cluster health:

```
    etcdctl --debug cluster-health
    Cluster-Endpoints: http://127.0.0.1:4001, http://127.0.0.1:2379
    cURL Command: curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:4001/v2/members
    cURL Command: curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:2379/v2/members
    member ce2a822cea30bfca is unhealthy: got unhealthy result from http://localhost:2379
    member da05b63349d818dc is unreachable: no available published client urls
    cluster is unhealthy
```

Note how this ignores the two nodes added previously, but sends requests to random port on localhost...

## Loader 2 10.11.51.174

At first this machine started OK, but after I saw there was something wrong with **Loader 1**, I tried adding **Loader 1** as a member from this machine, and now I see the same picture on this machine too. I.e. it tries to query this 4001 port, where nobody responds.  On all machines:

```
    netstat -tupln | grep etcd
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4507/etcd           
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4507/etcd           
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2380          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4507/etcd
```

Nobody listens on 4001...

## Loader 3 10.11.51.231

On this loader I didn't try to add new members. So it looks like this:

```
    etcdctl --debug cluster-health
    Cluster-Endpoints: http://127.0.0.1:4001, http://127.0.0.1:2379
    cURL Command: curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:4001/v2/members
    cURL Command: curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:2379/v2/members
    member ce2a822cea30bfca is healthy: got healthy result from http://localhost:2379
    cluster is healthy
```

In other words it still sends requests to random port, but this time it isn't bothered by the fact that nobody replied...

---

Below is the contents of the configuration files:

```
cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/etcd.service
[Unit]
Description=Etcd Server
After=network.target
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=notify
WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/etcd/
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/etcd/etcd.conf
User=etcd
# set GOMAXPROCS to number of processors
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "GOMAXPROCS=$(nproc) /usr/bin/etcd --name=\"${ETCD_NAME}\" --data-dir=\"${ETCD_DATA_DIR}\" --listen-client-urls=\"${ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS}\""
Restart=on-failure
LimitNOFILE=65536

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And:

```
cat /etc/etcd/etcd.conf
# [member]
ETCD_NAME=default
ETCD_DATA_DIR="/var/lib/etcd/default.etcd"
#ETCD_WAL_DIR=""
#ETCD_SNAPSHOT_COUNT="10000"
#ETCD_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL="100"
#ETCD_ELECTION_TIMEOUT="1000"
#ETCD_LISTEN_PEER_URLS="http://localhost:2380"
ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS="http://localhost:2379"
#ETCD_MAX_SNAPSHOTS="5"
#ETCD_MAX_WALS="5"
#ETCD_CORS=""
#
#[cluster]
#ETCD_INITIAL_ADVERTISE_PEER_URLS="http://localhost:2380"
# if you use different ETCD_NAME (e.g. test), set ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER value for this name, i.e. "test=http://..."
#ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER="default=http://localhost:2380"
#ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_STATE="new"
#ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_TOKEN="etcd-cluster"
ETCD_ADVERTISE_CLIENT_URLS="http://localhost:2379"
#ETCD_DISCOVERY=""
#ETCD_DISCOVERY_SRV=""
#ETCD_DISCOVERY_FALLBACK="proxy"
#ETCD_DISCOVERY_PROXY=""
#ETCD_STRICT_RECONFIG_CHECK="false"
#
#[proxy]
#ETCD_PROXY="off"
#ETCD_PROXY_FAILURE_WAIT="5000"
#ETCD_PROXY_REFRESH_INTERVAL="30000"
#ETCD_PROXY_DIAL_TIMEOUT="1000"
#ETCD_PROXY_WRITE_TIMEOUT="5000"
#ETCD_PROXY_READ_TIMEOUT="0"
#
#[security]
#ETCD_CERT_FILE=""
#ETCD_KEY_FILE=""
#ETCD_CLIENT_CERT_AUTH="false"
#ETCD_TRUSTED_CA_FILE=""
#ETCD_PEER_CERT_FILE=""
#ETCD_PEER_KEY_FILE=""
#ETCD_PEER_CLIENT_CERT_AUTH="false"
#ETCD_PEER_TRUSTED_CA_FILE=""
#
#[logging]
#ETCD_DEBUG="false"
# examples for -log-package-levels etcdserver=WARNING,security=DEBUG
#ETCD_LOG_PACKAGE_LEVELS=""
#
#[profiling]
#ETCD_ENABLE_PPROF="false"
```

So... what is going on? The error messages given by `etcd` are the typical mindless nonsense produced by Go built-ins. The HTTP server that `etcd` uses is again, the Go built-in junk, that produces non-standard and absolutely worthless replies. So I cannot understand what was (if at all) misconfigured / missing.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww Thank you for your very insightful and useful comment. I know, it's too much to ask, but iff you were so generous as to extend your knowledge to the mods by asking them to move this question to superuser or linux branches of SE, you would be truly indispensable.

Comment: You can flag the question and ask the moderators move it so you don't have to delete it on one site and create it on another site. For whatever reasons, the Stack Exchange network does not allow you to migrate it yourself. Also see [Author initiated migration to other SE sites?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851).